# A question introduced by "wonder"

Tags: grammar

> Granted that it is an idiomatic phrase, I still **wonder** how people came to say it**.**
>
> Granted that it is an idiomatic phrase, I still **wonder** how people came to say it**?**
>
> Granted..., I still **wonder** how **did** people came to say it**?**

I am interesting in wonder governing clause, but not exactly know how to use it. Which version is right? Which is the best?

Comment: It seems it's better suited for ELL: "Which version is right? Which is the best?" Before that, why not see usage examples online?

Answer (score 4):

When a question is quoted as indirect speech, there should not be a question mark after it. Question marks are reserved for questions that appear as questions on the surface—a quoted question is only a question underlyingly; on the surface, it is simply a quote acting as a noun phrase or clause. You can usually tell whether a question is quoted as indirect speech by the lack of [subject-auxiliary inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%2Dauxiliary_inversion).

In other words, your first example should not have a question mark:

> Granted that it is an idiomatic phrase, I still wonder how people came to say it.

In your second example, there is no subject-auxiliary inversion and the question therefore emerges as a surface-level question. Verbs like ‘wonder’ or ‘ask’, when followed by a clause, require that that clause be a relative clause (for example in the form of quoted indirect speech), and “How did people come to say it?” is a main clause, not a relative clause. The example is thus grammatically incorrect.

You can use verbs like ‘ask’ and ‘wonder’ as verbs of expression; as with ‘say’, these can simply be followed by a colon and then quoted direct speech. In such cases, if the direct speech is a question, it should of course be followed by a question mark, since it is not relative to anything, but stands quite on its own:

> Granted that it is an idiomatic phrase, I still wonder: how did people come to say it?

(Note: When you use ‘did’ as the auxiliary, the main verb, ‘come’, has to be in the infinitive, not in the past tense)